# Creating NSString from byte array generates wrong characters using Swift language

Tags: swift, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to decode some Unicode strings from a binary file. I know that they are encoded as UTF-16, and they have a 'big endian' BOM (0xFFFE). But when I try to turn them into a string I end up with a bunch of Chinese characters.

```
var bytes:[UInt8] = [0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x0E, 0xFE]
let text = NSString(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count, encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding)

print(text)
```

This prints Chinese ideograms and a [?] rather than "ABC‼︎", which is what (I believe) it should.

I've tried different encodings but nothing works correctly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Those bytes are {A, B, C, VARIATION SELECTOR-15} in UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 0):

The data sample you provide is coded little endian.

[image]

I don't know if it is you sample data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's probably something wrong with your input.

First, BOM should be placed as a first sequence in the input. Second, the order of bytes you provided are reversed.

This example shows correct parsing:

```
var bytes:[UInt8] = [0xFF, 0xFE, 0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00]
var text = NSString(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count, encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding)!

print(text) // prints "ABC\n"

bytes = [0xFE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43]
text = NSString(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count, encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding)!

print(text) // "ABC\n"
```